# Java Mapping range of IDs to Strings in List

Tags: java, list, dictionary, iso

I have the following code that will get me a list of all the country names :D

```
private List<String> countriesList = new ArrayList<String>();

public List<String> getCountriesList() {

   String[] locales = Locale.getISOCountries();

   for (String countryCode : locales) {

       Locale obj = new Locale("", countryCode);
       countriesList.add(obj.getDisplayCountry(Locale.ENGLISH));

   }
Collections.sort(countriesList);
countriesList.add(0, "International");
System.out.println(countriesList);
return countriesList;
}
```

What I need to do is now map all these countries to an ID number.

The ID number will start at: 32000006 and end at 32000260

I am not sure what I need to do to get the numbers mapped.. I know that basically I will pass an int through a method and then that method will match the ID that is passed through to the method and then I need it to return the country name.

I am not sure about how to go about this but one problem I have noticed is that ID 32000008 belongs to the country: Åland Islands but as it has a weird A it is at the end of my List. I still need it to have the ID 32000008 though.

If anyone has any idea about what I need to do to my method to finish this off I will be grateful.

Thanks :)

**UPDATE**
I tried using a HashMap and got this code:

```
public class test{

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        getCountriesList();
    }

    private static HashMap<Integer,String> countriesList = new HashMap<Integer,String>();

    public static void getCountriesList() {

       String[] locales = Locale.getISOCountries();

       for (String countryCode : locales) {
            int i = 32000007;
           Locale obj = new Locale("", countryCode);
           countriesList.put(i,obj.getDisplayCountry(Locale.ENGLISH));
            i++;
       }
    countriesList.put(32000006,"International");
    System.out.println(countriesList);
    }

}
```

Which outputs:
{32000006=International, 32000007=Zimbabwe}

Any ideas why it isn't working?

Comment: You know about HashMaps in Java?

Comment: @MB_CE no not really

Comment: so, HashMap is also part of Java Collection and it lets you add data with a key, something like `hashMap.put(key,value)` and similarly let's you get data by key as well. So you can use the ID as key while storing country data in the HashMap and later get it by ID. Take a look at them http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: @MB_CE see my edit :)

Answer (score 0):

`i` is a local variable of the loop. So at each iteration, it's reinitialized to 32000007. The variable must be declared out of the loop:

```
int i = 32000007;
for (String countryCode : locales) {
    Locale obj = new Locale("", countryCode);
    countriesList.put(i,obj.getDisplayCountry(Locale.ENGLISH));
    i++;
}
```

That said, instead of having a list of strings, and a map of IDs to strings, why don't you create a Country class with two fields: ID and label. Then use a loop to create a `List<Country>`? That would be much cleaner.

```
String[] locales = Locale.getISOCountries();
List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<>();
int i = 32000007;
for (String countryCode : locales) {
    Locale obj = new Locale("", countryCode);
    countries.add(new Country(i, obj.getDisplayCountry(Locale.ENGLISH)));
    i++;
}
```

Comment: What would be in the country class? Do you have a full working code?

Comment: As I said: a field `id` of type `int`, and a field `label` of type `String`. Plus the methods you want (probably getters to access the ID and the labels).

Comment: I don't get it.. How can it work with just that in the class? Surely it needs other things?

Comment: You design the class the way you want. The idea is to group the ID of a country and the label of a country in a single Country object. So that you can get a Country instance and print its ID and label, without needing a Map containing all the IDs and labels. I don't know what you mean with "work" and "doesn't work", since I have no idea what you want to achieve with the countries. All I know is that Java is an OO language, and that if you want to deal with countries having an ID and a label, the right thing to do is to have a class Country having an ID and a label.

Comment: If it is the right thing to do can u show me what the "right" thing actually is so I can learn from looking at the working thing?

Comment: How about you trying first? There are plenty of tutorials explaining classes fields and methods. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html

Comment: I tried with what I know and can do and put my code in the OP already... If i am asking for help it is cuz i dont know how this sud be done...

Comment: The point of my answer is 1. to explain why you only have one country in your map; 2. to suggest you create a Country class use a List<Country> instead of storing ID/label pairs in a Map. Have you tried creating a Country class with these two fields? Where is your best attempt? What did you have a problem with when trying?

Comment: I tried this and lots of other code I found online but it gives the ID numbers wrong. They have to be in a specific order. All the country names should be alphabetical and then the IDs are assigned one by one. But there is the catch of that one above country which I mentioned in the OP. Please check.

Comment: You probably want to use a Collator. Or simply to handle it specifically. I'm not sure I would rely on the list returned by Locale.getISOCountries() if you need an absolute numbering: it could very well change in the next JDK versions: countries appear and disappear regularly.